A question about congruence classes of Lie group representations
Let $\omega_1$, ..., $\omega_{n-1}$ be the fundamental weights of the group $G=\mathrm{SU}(n)$. The restriction of the irreducible representation $\lambda=a_1\omega_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\omega_{n-1}$ with nonnegative integers $a_i$ to the center $Z(G)$ is a trivial representation of $Z(G)$ if and only if $a_1\nu_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\nu_{n-1}$ is equal to $0$ modulo $n$, where $\nu=(1,2,...,n-1)$ is the congruence vector.
My question is as follows. The center $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of the group $K=S(U(p)\times U(q))\subset G$, $p\geq 1$, $q\geq 1$, $p+q=n$. The irreducible representations of $K$ are $\mu=b_1\omega_1+\cdots+b_{n-1}\omega_{n-1}$, where $b_p$ is integer and all other $b_i$'s are nonnegative integers. How to find which of them are trivial upon restriction to $Z(G)$? In other words, do there exists an analogue of the congruence vector for a compact, but not semisimple Lie group like $K$?

By "acts trivially on $Z(G)$", do you meant that the centre acts trivially on the representation?

Thanks, Callum! I will fix this mistake!

For a semisimple Lie group, the centre acts trivially exactly when the representation descends to a representation of the adjoint group (i.e. the quotient by the centre). This happens when the highest weight is "analytically integral" for the adjoint group. I assume these ideas can be extended to a reductive group like the one you are looking at although I'm not sure of the details.

Thanks again, Callum! I found the expression "analytically integral linear functional" in the book by Knapp "Lie groups. Beyond an introduction". I will study this material!
